# Why is my decision boundary wrong for logistic regression using gradient descent?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to solve a classification task using logistic regression. Part of my task is to plot the decision boundary. I find that the gradient of the decision boundary seems to be solved correctly by my algorithm but when plotting the boundary is too high and does not separate the points well. I cannot work out why this is and would be grateful for any advice to solve this issue.

```
data = open('Question5.mat');
x = data.x; y = data.y; % Extract data for ease of use

LR = 0.001; % Set tunable learning rate for gradient descent

w_est = [0; 0; 0];  % Set inital guess for a, b, and c

cost = [];  % Initalise array to hold value of cost function
figure;
for i = 1:20000     % Set iteration limit for gradient descent

    iteration_cost = 0; grad_a = 0; grad_b = 0; grad_c = 0;     % Set innial value of 0 for summed terms
    
    for m = 1:1100  % Iterate through data points
        y_hat_est = 1./(1+exp(-w_est'*[x(m,1); x(m,2); 1]));    % Calculate value of sigmoid function with estimated coefficients for each datapoint
        iteration_cost = iteration_cost + y(m)*log(y_hat_est)+(1-y(m))*log(1-y_hat_est);    % Calculate cost function and add it to summed term for each data point
        
        % Calculate each gradient term for each data point and add to
        % summed gradient
        grad_a = grad_a + (y_hat_est - y(m))*x(m,1);
        grad_b = grad_b + (y_hat_est - y(m))*x(m,2);
        grad_c = grad_c + (y_hat_est - y(m))*x(m,3);
    
    end
    
    
    g = [grad_a; grad_b; grad_c];   % Create vector of gradients
    
    w_est = w_est - LR*g;   % Update estimate vector with next term
    cost(i) = -iteration_cost;  % Add the value of the cost function to the array for costs
    
    if mod(i,1000) == 0    % Only plot on some iterations to speed up program
        hold off
        gscatter(x(:,1),x(:,2),y,'rb'); % Plot scatter plot grouped by class
        xlabel('x1'); ylabel('x2'); title(i);   % Add title and labels to figure
        hold on
        x1_plot = -6:4; x2_plot = -3:7; % Create array of values for plotting
        plot( -(w_est(1)*x1_plot + w_est(3)) /w_est(2), x2_plot);   % Plot decision boundary based on the current coefficient estimates

%         pause(1)  % Add delay to aid visualisation
end
end
hold off;
figure; plot(cost)  % Plot the cost function
title('Cost function'); xlabel('Iteration number'); ylabel('cost');
```

[image]
[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhlrn.png)

Comment: Maybe you can do a log-log plot on the cost function, that might give us more insights.

Comment: thank you for your help. I have tried to include the loglog plot of cost but it's not embedding as i would like however you can see it by clicking on the link 'enter image description here' at the bottom of my edited post

Comment: Thank you for the log-log plot, to my experience, that looks healthy. What picked my interest now is that the scale of the values. Two things out of my head is that, neither your data is not zero-centered nor has uniform scale. Your non-linear function seems to be sigmoid which might saturate on those higher values. Maybe you should try zero-centering first, -1 to 1 scaling second and combine those in third attempt.

Comment: My understanding was that logisitic regression would not need to be cenetered on 0,0 so long as the classes were lineary seperable. Am i mistaken in this? It is also possible i have misunderstood your explanation as this if a relatively new topic for me.